# Using Microsoft Membership Provider Outside of ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, membership

I'm trying to integrate with an already existing user base. They are using the membership providers, but my application is multiplayer for a mobile game. I guess my question is in two parts.

Can I use the membership provider classes in a non-asp.net application?

And if I can, how do I setup a Web.config file when not in a web application project?

Comment: you mean WebSecurity class? yes you can use it in other places.

Comment: I kind of figured you could, but wanted to make sure before I continued onward. So I know it is probably a super newb question, but how do you make the web.config file for something that isn't a web based project?

Comment: there is nothing magical about web.config. asp.net is basically taking those attributes inside web.config and feed them to appropriate classes. You can just do the same

Comment: Cool, thank you. If you wanted to write it up in a short answer or something, more than happy to mark it as answered. Don't really get the comments section. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use WebSecurity in other places, it is just a class after all. And there is nothing magical about web.config, asp.net is basically taking those attributes inside web.config and feed them to appropriate classes. Something like `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` . So you can just hard code them in or make your own config file to store those info.

Comment: WebSecurity is not Membership, although WebSecurity does use membership.  SimpleMembership is an extended form of MembershipProvider that exists in the WebSecurity namespace, but this is not necessarily what the OP was asking about.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch check out the comment, I did confirm that WebSecurity is what he wanted

Comment: So just a few moments ago I finished up the code for what I was doing here. I'll just say that I had the database prior for the membership provider. I didn't know if I could use Membership outside of ASP.Net. That was the original question that I asked, and was answered. Then I asked about Web.Config, I was making a class library project. Steve didn't have all the information to answer me properly I suppose. But my config settings needed to be in App.config. I just wanted to post this, in case someone comes across this thread with a similar issue. Still thank you very much Steve, very helpful.